# can't delete faces

Tags: edit-mode

I have imported curves from Adobe illustrator and converted to mesh and create a face (F). I can't delete "windows" faces of the arches. (deleting face doesn't work)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to transform my curves to 2D / fill -> front but the result when converting to mesh is not good.

[image]

In edit mode, I tried select all and the menu "mesh>clean up>limited dissolve.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before converting to mesh, try to set the curve to '2D' and change the 'fill mode'.

Comment: @lemon I did it but the result is not good after conversion to mesh (see image)

Comment: In edit mode, try select all and the menu "mesh>clean up>limited dissolve"

Comment: @lemon It's better. How can I achieve the face cleaning ?

Comment: Don't think you can do more (meaning 'the less edges possible'). Inner geometry is still many edges anyway. What do you expect by "achieve"? The point is: a single face cannot surround a hole.

Comment: @lemon is it possible to have only one face without any  small faces (see my update ?)

Comment: Wilcar, no, it is not. As said above, a unique face cannot surround a hole. But in object mode, will be invisible (until you don't use modifiers like bevel or subdivision as this kind of mesh won't work for that).

Comment: @lemon. Thank you for your help